# CSS: Set border to half width

Tags: html, css

Consider following:

```
<div class="box">
...
</div>

.box{
    width:500px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

It will set the bottom border of full width of the box (500px).
But instead of setting the border bottom to whole width, I'd like to set 300px, in the middle of the box bottom, how should I do that..

Comment: can you put a centered `<hr>` at the bottom of your box? Then you can style it exactly how you need it.

Comment: Actually padding is for controlling that.

Comment: @micha that will also pad the content within the `box`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you throw an `<hr>` at the bottom of your box?

```
<div class="box">
    ...
    <hr>
</div>

.box{
    width:500px;
}

.box hr{
    width: 300px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/MuAKF/](https://jsfiddle.net/MuAKF/235/)

Comment: I have downvoted this answer not because it's wrong - it's a perfectly valid solution IF you have a way to influence the HTML structure. But there's a better answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032086/5108832 and it's better because it's a pure CSS solution

Comment: @dev_masta FYI: this post is from 2012. I would imagine a lot has changed in a decade! Happy programming :)

Comment: Sorry man, I would actually like @user1117313 to change the selected answer and not cause you to lose points.
Will make up for that on some of your other answers ;)

Comment: @dev_masta You don't need to/should not downvote answers in SO just because a better one exists.

Comment: Sorry guys, when I look at it now, I don't know why I bothered to downvote it, like I said, it's a perfectly valid solution although not 100% CSS solution, but SO won't allow me to change my vote now unless the post is edited.

Answer (score 46):

You can Use ::after or ::before pseudo-selectors.
Like:

```
<div> something here </div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cU368/)

Comment: You can use the same solution to a vertical border.

Comment: here's a problem, can I use **content** section in any way to draw a border? without using **border** property? just wondering

Comment: If you don't want an actual border, you could define `height: 1px;` and then set a `background: red;` on the pseudo-element

Answer (score 6):

```
.box {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc,#ccc);
    background-size: 50% 2px;
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: as of 2022, this should be the accepted answer, simple & elegant

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```css
    .box {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
    }
    .border {
        position: aboslute;
        background: #ccc;
        left: 100px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 1px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
        <div class="border">
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

But there are infinite possibilities. Some are more semantically correct than others; this solution is simply a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a background-image:

```
.box{
    width:500px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-image:(yourimage.png); /*make your image a solid line 1px tall by 250px wide (or so)*/
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Yes! And you can also use CSS Gradients to generate the image in CSS if it's a simple gradient or solid color: `background-image: linear-gradient(black, black); background-size: 50% 1px; background-position: 50% 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like this, works well in Firefox

```
<style type="text/css">

.box{

    width: 500px;

    height: 20px;

}

.boxHalfWidth{

    width: 250px;

    height: 1px;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="box">

some data

<div class="boxHalfWidth"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of extra HTML elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
css:
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 50%; 
    padding-top: 20px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work. It isn't clear what you intend the reader to do with the CSS you provide. When answering eight year old questions with seven existing answers it is really important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.